# XSL-FO page breaks, widows and orphans

Tags: xml, xslt, xsl-fo

I have a large corpus producing a PDF based on XSL-FO 3.0 transformation of the following simplified XML structure:

```
<corpus>
  <deposition>
     <text>
       <deposition-title>foo title</deposition-title>
       <seg>foo paragraph 1</seg>
       <seg>foo paragraph 2</seg>
       <seg>foo paragraph 3</seg>
       <appnotes>
         <appitem>foo apparatus item 1</appitem>
       </appnotes>
       <footnotes>
         <footitem>foo note 1</footitem>
         <footitem>foo note 1</footitem>
       </footnotes>
     </text>
  </deposition>
  <deposition>
     <text>
       <deposition-title>foo title</deposition-title>
       <seg>foo paragraph 1</seg>
       <seg>foo paragraph 2</seg>
      <appnotes/>
       <footnotes>
         <footitem>foo note 1</footitem>
       </footnotes>
     </text>
  </deposition>
   [...]
</corpus>
```

I use XSL-FO 3.0 that looks like the following (minus some inline markup for superscripts and italics):

```
<xsl:stylesheet 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" 
xmlns:xd="http://www.pnp-software.com/XSLTdoc"
version="3.0">

<xsl:template match="/">
    <fo:root>
        <fo:layout-master-set>
            <fo:simple-page-master 
                master-name="page-recto"
                page-height="29.7cm"  page-width="21cm"
                margin-top="2cm" margin-bottom="2cm" 
                margin-left="3cm" margin-right="1.5cm">
                <fo:region-body 
                    region-name="xsl-region-body"/>
            </fo:simple-page-master>
        </fo:layout-master-set>

        <fo:page-sequence master-reference="page-recto">
            <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body" 
                font-family="Times" font-weight="normal" 
                font-size="8pt" space-before="8pt" space-after="8pt"
                text-align="justify" end-indent="120pt">
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </fo:flow>
        </fo:page-sequence>

    </fo:root>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="text">
    <fo:block widows="10" orphans="10"
        font-size="9pt" font-weight="bold" 
        padding-bottom="1cm" end-indent="120pt">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </fo:block>
</xsl:template>


<xsl:template match="seg">
    <fo:block
        font-family="Times" font-weight="normal" line-height="12pt" line-stacking-strategy="font-height"
        font-size="10pt" space-before="10pt" space-after="10pt" text-align="justify" end-indent="120pt">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </fo:block>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="appnotes">
   <xsl:choose>
       <xsl:when test="./appitem">
            <fo:leader leader-pattern="rule" leader-length="2cm" rule-style="solid" rule-thickness=".2pt"/>      
            <fo:block font-size="8pt" font-weight="normal" end-indent="120pt">
                <xsl:for-each select="./appitem">
                    <fo:inline keep-together="always"><xsl:apply-templates/>&#160;&#160;&#160;</fo:inline>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </fo:block></xsl:when>
       <xsl:otherwise></xsl:otherwise>
   </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="footnotes">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="./footitem">
            <fo:leader leader-pattern="rule" leader-length="2cm" rule-style="solid" rule-thickness=".2pt"/>  
                <xsl:for-each select="./footitem">
                    <fo:block font-size="8pt" font-weight="normal" end-indent="120pt">
                       <xsl:apply-templates/>
                    </fo:block>
                </xsl:for-each>
            <fo:leader leader-pattern="rule" leader-length="2cm" rule-style="solid" rule-thickness=".2pt"/>      
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <fo:leader leader-pattern="rule" leader-length="2cm" rule-style="solid" rule-thickness=".2pt"/>      
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

It produces repeatable sections like generally look like this:

[image: Nice output, no bad page breaks]

But the XSL-FO produces some page break problems which I can't seem to solve using combinations of keep together, widows, orphans, etc.

`<deposition-title>` breaks from `<seg>`

[image: Title split from content]

`<seg>` breaks from  `<appnotes>` and `<footnotes>`

[image: Content split from appnotes/footnotes]

Goals: I'd like to apply the following two rules for page breaking any  `<text>`:

1. `<deposition-title>` sticks to the first `<seg>`
2. `<appnotes>` and `<footnotes>` sticks to the final `<seg>`

Thanks in advance for any insight.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you add

```
<xsl:template match="deposition-title">
    <fo:block keep-with-next="always">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </fo:block>
</xsl:template>
```

then the title should be put on the same page as the first seg block you produce.

A similar construction with `keep-with-previous` should do for the appnotes and footnotes, as I understand you want to keep them both together with the last `seg` block so perhaps changing the `<xsl:apply-templates/>` in the template matching `text` should be changed to `<xsl:apply-templates select="node() except footnotes/>` and then in the template matching `appnotes` you create the wrapper and process the footnotes e.g.

```
<xsl:template match="appnotes">
  <fo:block keep-with-previous="always">
    ...
    <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::footnotes"/>
  </fo:block>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Marvellously simple. Thanks very much!

Comment: As I inspect the result closer, I realise that this solution worked to keep the title with the first seg block. However it does not do so for the appnotes and footnotes: I took everything within the existing templates and wrapped them in `<fo:block keep-with-previous="always">`. Yet for example the first `<fo:leader>`will split from the rest of appnotes. Thanks.

Comment: Do you have one `fo:block` wrapper for the appnotes and the footnotes together? It might also help to add information to the question and as a tag as to which FO processor you use, I must admit my knowledge of how well these XSL-FO properties work in practice with different implementations is rather limited but I have seen answers around here suggesting that there are experienced users of various products that can give you more specific suggestions if you mention your FO processor.

Comment: I'm not sure why I didn't think to put it into one template, but even doing, with one block, that has not solved the problem. However I added the same property to each sub block, leader, etc. - and now it all holds together. This is being processed with RenderX. Thanks! (I've added the revised code in a response to my own question, incase someone comes along and sees the problem).

Answer (score 1):

In followup to the accepted answer, I'm posting the revised code here for the one problem identified in the comments. Now `<appnotes>`and `<footnotes>` are one template, inside one `<fo:block>`. This is processed with RenderX.

```
<xsl:template match="footnotes | appnotes">
    <fo:block font-size="8pt" font-weight="normal" end-indent="120pt" keep-with-previous="always">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="./appitem">
                <fo:leader leader-pattern="rule" leader-length="2cm" rule-style="solid" rule-thickness=".2pt" keep-with-previous="always"/>      
                <fo:block keep-with-previous="always">
                    <xsl:for-each select="./appitem">
                        <fo:inline><xsl:apply-templates/>&#160;&#160;&#160;</fo:inline>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </fo:block>
            </xsl:when>
        </xsl:choose>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="./footitem">
                <fo:leader leader-pattern="rule" leader-length="2cm" rule-style="solid" rule-thickness=".2pt" keep-with-previous="always"/>  
                <xsl:for-each select="./footitem">
                    <fo:block keep-with-previous="always">
                        <xsl:apply-templates/>
                    </fo:block>
                </xsl:for-each>     
                <fo:leader leader-pattern="rule" leader-length="2cm" rule-style="solid" rule-thickness=".2pt" keep-with-previous="always"/> 
            </xsl:when>
        </xsl:choose>
    </fo:block>
</xsl:template>
```